# JTable in JPanel only shows all its values when scrolling on it or by showing-hidding-showing the JPanel on runtime manually

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I am working in a Java desktop game where I am trying to display some panels composed by a `JTable` with a `JScrollPane`, which has only one column and several rows, containing the data I want to display. This panels are not visible when the application starts, because they are shown depending on the `JButton` pressed.

When I start my application, these panels are already added to the frame, but not visible. At the moment I try to display them by pressing the corresponding button, they are shown, but not all the rows are visible. If I press the button again, the panel is hidden, and if I press again the button to display it again, now it is shown with all its rows visible.

For some reason, just by setting its visibility to true -> false -> true by pressing the corresponding button, the `JTable` of the panel displays all its rows, but when I display it the first time, it doesn't... I need to do it twice.

To check this, I try to set the panel visibility to true -> false -> true when the application starts programmatically, but it doesn't works. It only works if I press the button that displays the panel (remember, twice, the first time it doesn't shows all the rows, the second time it does). Also, I've checked by debugging if, at the moment I set the panel visibility to true the first time, it has all the data inside, and it is correct, so it is something just only graphic, because the data is there. Also I realized that by scrolling with the mouse the first time I show the panel, it shows all the data, so I guess it must be refreshing something when I scroll, or when I show the panel for the second time I press the corresponding button.

I've tried to `revalidate()` and `repaint()` the table, to `fireTableDataChanged()` and `fireTableStructureChanged()` the model of the table. Also I've created a thread which starts at the same time the application starts, which sets the visibility of these panels to true and false at the beginning, and revalidating the tables, just to try to see what could be happening when showing/hidding the panels.

After create this thread, I realized that if I set the visibility of this panels to true from the beginning, I see how the UI thread "refresh" the panels in some way, as I can see them uncomplete, and after complete, in a split second. But after, I have to close them manually, because I cannot control (I tried) the time needed to see them filled before close them.

Here is a picture of the panel when I `setVisible(true)` one of these panels:
[image: Panel Uncomplete]

And here is the picture of the same panel when I hide and show it again (manually), without perform any other actions:
[image: Panel complete]

Here is the code of the table model set in the JTable of the panel:

```
/**
 * Class to create the model instance for the selector panel list
 */
public class CustomTableModelForPredefinedMessagesSelectorKeyboard extends DefaultTableModel {

    private ArrayList selectedList = new ArrayList<>();

    public CustomTableModelForPredefinedMessagesSelectorKeyboard() {
        this.addColumn(LanguageConfiguration.getLanguageSelected().getString("selection"));
        //setListType(ListType.PREDEFINED_MESSAGES);
        setListType();
    }

    /**
     * Function to get the size of the list
     *
     * @return the list size
     */
    //@Override
    public int getSize() {
        return selectedList.size();
    }

    /**
     * Function to get the element of a specific index from the list
     *
     * @param index index of the message to be retrieved
     * @return the message text of the corresponding index
     */

    public Object getElementAt(int index) {
        return selectedList.get(index).toString();
    }

    public ArrayList getSelectedList() {
        return selectedList;
    }

    public void setSelectedList(ArrayList selectedList) {
        this.selectedList = selectedList;
    }

    /**
     * Function to set the list of the selector panel according to the list type selected
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void setListType() {

        selectedList.add("selectorPanel_PredefMsg_EnemyOnSight");
        selectedList.add("selectorPanel_PredefMsg_GreenAlert");
        selectedList.add("selectorPanel_PredefMsg_HowAreYou");
        selectedList.add("selectorPanel_PredefMsg_InminentAttack");
        selectedList.add("selectorPanel_PredefMsg_No");
        selectedList.add("selectorPanel_PredefMsg_Positioned");
        selectedList.add("selectorPanel_PredefMsg_Ready");
        selectedList.add("selectorPanel_PredefMsg_RedAlert");
        selectedList.add("selectorPanel_PredefMsg_ReturnToBase");
        selectedList.add("selectorPanel_PredefMsg_TargetOutOfReach");
        selectedList.add("selectorPanel_PredefMsg_WaitingOrders");
        selectedList.add("selectorPanel_PredefMsg_WeHaveAProblem");
        selectedList.add("selectorPanel_PredefMsg_YellowAlert");
        selectedList.add("selectorPanel_PredefMsg_Yes");

        for (Object string : selectedList)
            this.addRow(new Object[]{LanguageConfiguration.getLanguageSelected().getString((String) string)});

        if (SwingInterfaceSubJPanels.getPredefinedMessagesSelectorJPanel() != null)
            for (Component component : SwingInterfaceSubJPanels.getPredefinedMessagesSelectorJPanel().getComponents())
                if (component instanceof JScrollPane) {
                    JScrollPane messagesListScrollPane = (JScrollPane) component;
                    JViewport viewport = messagesListScrollPane.getViewport();
                    preselectFirstElement((CustomJTable) viewport.getView());
                    break;
                }

    }

    /**
     * Function to pre-select the firs item of the list in the selector list
     *
     * @param customJTable the table where the selection will be performed
     */
    private void preselectFirstElement(CustomJTable customJTable) {
        if (customJTable.getRowCount() > 0)
            customJTable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(0, 0);
    }

}
```

And here is the code of the panel:

```
/**
 * Class to create and manage a selector keyboard
 */
public class PredefinedMessagesSelectorKeyboard extends JPanel {

    /**
     * Color of shadow
     */
    private final Color shadowColor;
    /**
     * Double values for Horizontal and Vertical radius of corner arcs
     */
    private final Dimension arcs;
    /**
     * Variables to get the coordinates of the mouse on mouse click event over the jpanel
     */
    private int xJPanelCoord, yJPanelCoord;

    Component componentToManage;
    SelectorConfirmationController.Type selectorPanelType;


    /**
     * Constructor to create the selector panel structure and add its components
     */
    public PredefinedMessagesSelectorKeyboard() {
        DisplayMode displayMode = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDisplayMode();
        double screenWidth = displayMode.getWidth();
        double screenHeight = displayMode.getHeight();

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) Math.round(screenWidth * 0.35), (int) Math.round(screenHeight * 0.6)));
        //this.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(5, 122, 122));
        this.setBackground(new Color(150, 150, 150));

        addSelectorPanelComponents();

        setVisible(false);
        setOpaque(false);
        makeJPanelDraggable();
        shadowColor = Color.black;
        arcs = new Dimension(100, 100);
    }

    /**
     * Function to add the components of the JPanel
     */
    private void addSelectorPanelComponents() {
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        addSelectorPanelJTable();
        addSelectorPanelButtons();
        addSelectorPanelCloseJButton();
    }

    /**
     * Function to add the panel with the elements available for selection
     */
    private void addSelectorPanelJTable() {
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 4;
        gridBagConstraints.gridheight = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(40, 20, 20, 0);

        CustomTableModelForPredefinedMessagesSelectorKeyboard customTableModelForPredefinedMessagesSelectorPanelList = new CustomTableModelForPredefinedMessagesSelectorKeyboard();
        CustomJTable predefinedMessagesselectorPanelJTable = new CustomJTable(customTableModelForPredefinedMessagesSelectorPanelList);
        predefinedMessagesselectorPanelJTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        predefinedMessagesselectorPanelJTable.setName("predefinedMessagesSelectorPanelJTable");

        JScrollPane selectorJTableJScrollPane = new JScrollPane(predefinedMessagesselectorPanelJTable);
        selectorJTableJScrollPane.getViewport().setBackground(new Color(24, 27, 34));
        add(selectorJTableJScrollPane, gridBagConstraints);
    }

    /**
     * Function to add the close panel button and the selection confirmation button
     */
    private void addSelectorPanelButtons() {
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 4;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(20, 20, 0, 20);

        JButton selectPreviousButton = createScaledSwingShapedButton("/images/boton_popup_panel_selector_anterior.png",
                "/images/boton_popup_panel_selector_anterior_seleccionado.png");
        selectPreviousButton.setName("selectorPanelPreviousButton");
        selectPreviousButton.setToolTipText(LanguageConfiguration.getLanguageSelected().getString("tooltipTextPreviousButton"));
        selectPreviousButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            for (Component component : getComponents())
                if (component instanceof JScrollPane) {
                    JScrollPane messagesListScrollPane = (JScrollPane) component;
                    JViewport viewport = messagesListScrollPane.getViewport();
                    selectPrevious((CustomJTable) viewport.getView());
                    break;
                }
        });

        JButton confirmSelectedButton = createScaledSwingShapedButton("/images/boton_popup_panel_selector_confirmar.png",
                "/images/boton_popup_panel_selector_confirmar_seleccionado.png");
        confirmSelectedButton.setName("selectorPanelConfirmButton");
        confirmSelectedButton.setToolTipText(LanguageConfiguration.getLanguageSelected().getString("tooltipTextConfirmButton"));
        confirmSelectedButton.addActionListener(new SelectorConfirmationController(componentToManage, selectorPanelType));

        JButton selectNextButton = createScaledSwingShapedButton("/images/boton_popup_panel_selector_siguiente.png",
                "/images/boton_popup_panel_selector_siguiente_seleccionado.png");
        selectNextButton.setName("selectorPanelNextButton");
        selectNextButton.setToolTipText(LanguageConfiguration.getLanguageSelected().getString("tooltipTextNextButton"));
        selectNextButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            for (Component component : getComponents()){
                if (component instanceof JScrollPane){
                    JScrollPane messagesListScrollPane = (JScrollPane) component;
                    JViewport viewport = messagesListScrollPane.getViewport();
                    selectNext((CustomJTable) viewport.getView());
                    break;
                }
            }
        });

        JPanel lateralButtonsPanel = new JPanel();
        lateralButtonsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(lateralButtonsPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        lateralButtonsPanel.setOpaque(false);
        lateralButtonsPanel.setName("lateralButtonsPanel");
        lateralButtonsPanel.add(selectPreviousButton);
        lateralButtonsPanel.add(confirmSelectedButton);
        lateralButtonsPanel.add(selectNextButton);
        add(lateralButtonsPanel, gridBagConstraints);
    }

    /**
     * Function to create and add the close panel button to the panel
     */
    private void addSelectorPanelCloseJButton() {

        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 4;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        //gridBagConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(20, 20, 0, 20);

        JButton closeMessagesConsoleButton = createScaledSwingShapedButton("/images/boton_consola_mensajes_2.png",
                "/images/boton_consola_mensajes_2_seleccionado.png");
        closeMessagesConsoleButton.setName("selectorPanelCloseButton");
        closeMessagesConsoleButton.setToolTipText(LanguageConfiguration.getLanguageSelected().getString("tooltipTextClosePanelButton"));
        //closeMessagesConsoleButton.addActionListener(e -> setVisible(false));
        closeMessagesConsoleButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                /*if (getComponentToManage().getName().equals("messageBoxTable"))*/
                    SwingInterfaceSubJPanels.getMainScreenUpperInformationLabel().setVisible(false);
                setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        add(closeMessagesConsoleButton, gridBagConstraints);
    }

    /**
     * Function to select the next item of the list in the selector list
     * @param customJTable the table where the selection will be performed
     */
    private void selectPrevious(CustomJTable customJTable){
        if (customJTable.getSelectedRow() > 0) {
            customJTable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(customJTable.getSelectedRow() - 1, customJTable.getSelectedRow() - 1);
            customJTable.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(customJTable.getCellRect(customJTable.getSelectedRow()-1, 0, true)));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to select the next item of the list in the selector list
     * @param customJTable the table where the selection will be performed
     */
    private void selectNext(CustomJTable customJTable){
        if (customJTable.getSelectedRow() >= 0 && customJTable.getSelectedRow() < customJTable.getRowCount()-1) {
            customJTable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(customJTable.getSelectedRow() + 1, customJTable.getSelectedRow() + 1);
            customJTable.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(customJTable.getCellRect(customJTable.getSelectedRow()+1, 0, true)));
        }
    }

    public Component getComponentToManage() {
        return componentToManage;
    }

    public void setComponentToManage(Component componentToManage) {
        this.componentToManage = componentToManage;
    }

    public SelectorConfirmationController.Type getSelectorPanelType() {
        return selectorPanelType;
    }

    public void setSelectorPanelType(SelectorConfirmationController.Type selectorPanelType) {
        this.selectorPanelType = selectorPanelType;
    }

    /**
     * Function to create and return a scaled swing shaped button with its corresponding images
     *
     * @param buttonImage        button image when the button is not pressed
     * @param buttonPressedImage button image when the button is pressed
     * @return the button already built
     */
    private JButton createScaledSwingShapedButton(String buttonImage, String buttonPressedImage) {

        Image scaledImage;

        try {
            SwingShapedButton swingShapedButton = new SwingShapedButton();
            JButton newButton = (JButton) swingShapedButton.createComponent(SwingShapedButton.ButtonShape.ROUND);
            Image imageButton = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(buttonImage));
            scaledImage = scaleImage(imageButton);
            newButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(scaledImage));
            Image imageButtonPressed = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(buttonPressedImage));
            scaledImage = scaleImage(imageButtonPressed);
            newButton.setPressedIcon(new ImageIcon(scaledImage));

            return newButton;

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            DataBase.database.insertSystemErrorLog(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName(), e);
            return (JButton) new SwingShapedButton().createComponent(SwingShapedButton.ButtonShape.ROUND);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Function to scale the images of the buttons according to the screen resolution
     *
     * @param imageButton the image to be set to the button
     * @return the image resized
     */
    private Image scaleImage(Image imageButton) {
        return imageButton.getScaledInstance((int) Math.round(((BufferedImage) imageButton).getWidth() * InterfaceControlsManager.getWidth_percentage()),
                (int) Math.round(((BufferedImage) imageButton).getHeight() * InterfaceControlsManager.getHeight_percentage()),
                Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    }

    /**
     * Function to allow the panel to be draggable over the frame
     */
    private void makeJPanelDraggable() {
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                xJPanelCoord = e.getX();
                yJPanelCoord = e.getY();
            }
        });
        this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                int x = e.getXOnScreen() - xJPanelCoord;
                int y = e.getYOnScreen() - yJPanelCoord;
                setLocation(x, y);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Function to set the appearance of the panel
     *
     * @param g the graphics to be set
     */
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        /*
          Distance between shadow border and opaque panel border
         */
        int shadowGap = 5;
        int shadowAlpha = 10;
        Color shadowColorA = new Color(shadowColor.getRed(),
                shadowColor.getGreen(), shadowColor.getBlue(), shadowAlpha);
        Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;

        //Sets antialiasing if HQ.

        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        //Draws shadow borders if any.
        int strokeSize = 1;
        boolean shady = true;
        graphics.setColor(shadowColorA);
        int shadowOffset = 4;
        graphics.fillRoundRect(
                shadowOffset,// X position
                shadowOffset,// Y position
                width - strokeSize - shadowOffset, // width
                height - strokeSize - shadowOffset, // height
                arcs.width, arcs.height);// arc Dimension

        //Draws the rounded opaque panel with borders.
        graphics.setColor(getBackground());
        graphics.fillRoundRect(0, 0, width - shadowGap,
                height - shadowGap, arcs.width, arcs.height);
        graphics.setColor(getForeground());
        graphics.setStroke(new BasicStroke(strokeSize));
        graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, width - shadowGap,
                height - shadowGap, arcs.width, arcs.height);

        //Sets strokes to default, is better.
        graphics.setStroke(new BasicStroke());
    }

}
```

Can someone explain to me why I see this effect in the panel? There is some reason why the JTable doesn't show its data the first time I `setVisible(true)` the panel, but it is displayed properly the second time? Could be something with the UI, or maybe I am not realizing about something here?

Thanks for any comment you can give me!

Comment: Do you by any chance encounter an exception in your awt thread while opening the table for first time? E.g. an Nullpointer, this might cut off the rendering of the table.

Comment: @SnowmanXL no I didn't :( ... I am not getting any exception when executing the application, nor while opening the table. That's why I'm getting crazy with this

Comment: *these panels are already added to the frame, but not visible.* - don't know what that means. If the panels occupy the same location on the frame then you should either 1) use a CardLayout to control with panel is visible, or 2) Add the panel to the viewport of the scroll pane when you want to swap panels. The panels should not just be sitting on the frame invisible. * Also I've created a thread*  - all Swing components should be created and updated on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). You should NOT use a separate Thread to change the visibility of the components.

Comment: I don't like the design of your TableModel. It appears you have two copies of the data. You invoke addRow(...) to add the data to the DefaultTableModel, but then you keep a copy in your model class. The data should only be in one place. There is no need for a `getSize()` method. That method is implemented in the DefaultTableModel. The `getSelectedList()` method should get the data by using the `getValueAt(...)` method in  a loop. You should NOT be referencing a JScrollPane in a TableModel. A TableModel only stores data and should  know nothing about the container the JTable is added to.

Comment: @camickr thanks for your advices! About the panels, yes, I create all of them and add them to the frame in the same location, but only one is visible at the same time, so I dont have any problem about display them and see them properly in their location. They are completely independent, so I cannot use a CardLayout, as I don't want any reference of other panels when I am displaying one of them. Why you think it is not a good idea to have them invisible when the application starts? About the thread, it was just for testing some stuff, so I've already deleted from the project

Comment: @camickr about your second comment, the selectedList ArrayList I have, is just to have all the rows that will be added to the JTable in one place. Thought it would be easier to manage after, and the method getSelectedList() now has not any usages. I wrote it just in case I need the list from some other class of the package. About the reference of the JScrollPane, you're right, it is commented because now I'm doing that from outside of the TableModel. I going to work on these advices you give me but, you think these thing are related with the effect I'm having with the JTables visibility?

Comment: @camickr as you can see in the pictures, the first one that has the JTable half visible, you can see how the last row visible is has only visible a very small part of the row, showing that it is there, but not displayed properly. You think these advices you give could have some relation with this issue I'm having? Thanks a lot!

Comment: *They are completely independent, so I cannot use a CardLayout,* - That is the reason for using the CardLayout. They are independent, so one will only ever be visible at a time. *the selectedList ArrayList I have, is just to have all the rows that will be added to the JTable in one place* - they are in one place. They are in the TableModel. There is no need to duplicate the data! *You think these advices you give could have some relation with this issue* - I don't know what the issue is. I only know incorrect design can cause potential problems. I have never had problems like this.

Comment: @camickr thanks for your comments! I will check this design with your advices and will check again if that could be the reason. What I saw in the Oracle wiki about CardLayouts is that they are separated using tabs or a combo, which for me makes them not independents, in the way the user would be able to change between tabs, which is something that can happen, as the user must be able to open the different panels by clicking on different buttons of the application, not being able to swap between that panels in the way Oracle shows on its wiki, am I wrong or this can also be done with this comp?

Comment: *as the user must be able to open the different panels by clicking on different buttons of the application* - How is clicking on a button any different than clicking on a tab or an item in a combo box? What is relevant is the action that is taken once the user clicks on some component. Using a button is no different than using a combo box. In both cases you have an ActionListener which determines which panel is displayed in the CardLayout.

Comment: @camickr ok, I will explain this. I am able to open different panels from different butons, as you say, using an ActionListener, but one panel can refers to predefined messages (from the messages button), other to language (from the language button), or other to coordinates formats (from the coordinates format button). All these panels are independent and has no sense have them together in the same CardLayout, being able to switch among them. They must be opened only clicking on their corresponding button. Can a CardLayout hide tabs? And can a CardLayout mantain this look&feel of the panels?

Comment: 1) if panels occupy the same physical space on the frame and only one is visible at a time you use a CardLayout. 2) I already stated being the panels should be independent of one another, since only one can ever be displayed at a time.

Comment: @camickr maybe I am not explaining well myself. By using a CardLayout, is true, only one panel is displayed at a time, and using this CardLayout, each panel is independent of one another. The problem I have with the CardLayout, is that I can switch between the panels while the CardLayout is being displayed (by using the tabs or the combobox you referred before. This switching can be hidden or avoided? It is possible to hide the tabs or the combobox of the CardLayout and display only the panel I need programmatically? Switching between panels in the CardLayout is not allowed in my project.

Comment: The combo box is irrelevant and not needed. It is NOT part of the `CardLayout`!!! To swap a panel all you need to do is invoke the `show(...)` method of the `CardLayout`. The tutorial demo code just gives an example of how to use the `show(...)` method in an `ActionListener`. The demo could have used two buttons instead of the combo box. You stated before that **"the user must be able to open the different panels by clicking on different buttons of the application"**. So the `ActionListener` for the `button` invokes the `show(...)` method. I don't how to state it any clearer than that